# Persistent Storage of Relational Data

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, plist

I'm currently in the process of learning iOS Programming by creating a small game. This game is going to be a sports management style game which will mean there's a hefty amount of initial information that needs to be included in the app. For instance, Players, Clubs, Countries; all of which will be pretty large and will be relational.

From there I'll need to store the state of that data when a user saves, for instance a player may have changed club in the save and so the data in that particular save will be different from the initial data.

I've been looking into pLists, CoreData and SQLite but I'm unsure of which to use or how to combine them? Potentially have initial data loaded into the app from an SQLite database and then archive the objects from there?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SQLite or CoreData are your only real options here. There are plenty of existing questions covering the pros and cons of each.

Comment: Basically all you need for persistence is a file.  The file can be a properties file, a SQLite file, CoreData, or even a JSON file.  Each has its advantages/disadvantages, but CoreData is the "Apple preferred" approach for cases where you don't have a reason to the contrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest you CoreDate for keeping Players, Clubs, Countries. Your model will be then relational, and it's quite easy to retrieve the infos you need later. For the game settings, user's score, you can use NSUSERDEFAULTS which allow you to store small data individually.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. How would I go about creating that initial CoreData "database"?

Comment: You can try this tutorial : http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/. For NSUSERDEFAULTS, http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/